# Email attachment problem

Tags: python, email, attachment

I want to send an email with an attachment using the following code (Python 3.1)
(greatly simplified to show the example)

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = from_addr
msg['To'] = to_addr
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))

fp = open(att_file)
msg1 = MIMEText(fp.read())
attachment = msg1.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=att_file)
msg.attach(attachment)

# set string to be sent as 3rd parameter to smptlib.SMTP.sendmail()
send_string = msg.as_string()
```

The attachment object msg1 returns 'email.mime.text.MIMEText' object at ', but when the msg1.add_header(...) line runs the result is None, hence the program falls-over in msg.as_string() because no part of the attachment can have a None value.  (Traceback shows "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_content_maintype'" in line 118 of _dispatch in generator.py, many levels down from msg.as_string())

Has anyone any idea what the cause of the problem might be?  Any help would be appreciated.

Alan Harris-Reid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
msg.attach(msg1)
```

Comment: @Alan Harris-Reid: If my answer helped you, while it is trivial, you can accept it.

Comment: How do I accept it? Do you mean 'vote-up'?  If so, I cannot at present because vote-up requires 15 reputation, which I don't have yet. (Excuse my ignorance, but I'm new to all this.).  Regards.

Comment: Found it!  Discovered the tick below the vote-count.  Regards.

Comment: Got the reputation qualification now, so you can have a vote as well!